# iOS 10 Push Notification with MapView

Tags: ios, push-notification, mkmapview

I'm creating a scheduled push notification for app that presents local notifications. The annotation in the notification contains an MKMapView and an annotation pin on a single location (much like the built-in Find My Friends App). The map view works fine as long as the app is in the foreground but it doesn't work if the app is idle or stopped.

So the question is, should it be possible to render a live map view in an iOS 10 notifcation if the app is not running? If so, any any tips on how to handle the mapview differently when app is running versus not?

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes, turns out we were trying to draw the map in the push notification icons itself, which is not supported. So we just use a static map image for the default notification and then display the MapView once the rich notification is requested.